# Change drive in git bash for windows

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I was trying to navigate to my drive location `E:/Study/Codes` in `git bash` in windows. In command prompt in order to change drive I use `E:` It returns an error in `git bash`.

> bash: E:: command not found.

How do I change my current directory location from `/c/users` to `E:Study/Codes`

Answer (score 349):

In order to navigate to a different drive just use

```
cd /E/Study/Codes
```

Comment: I think the method has changed. The method in this answer didn't work. I had to use,
`cd /mnt/e/Study/Codes`
to navigate to that folder.

Comment: @ponir I think method is still same as Jagrati define. It worked for Git 2.14.1 64 bit version recent release as well.

Comment: @Benvorth Can you please clarify your comment? (Case does not seem to matter for drive letters on Windows.)

Comment: @skomisa if you use the `/mnt/...` notation mentioned by @ponir above the drive letter case was an issue for me...

Comment: When using this one (https://git-scm.com/download/win) only cd /C/ worked for me, cd /mnt/C/ or cd /mnt/c/ does not work for me. Has to be something special.

Comment: I agree with answer from Jagrati.

Do a quick check with 'pwd'.
I the current working directory is shown as something starting with /c/.. then use /e/Sudy/Codes to access E: drive.
If the result of 'pwd' shows something starting with /mnt/c/... then to access the E: drive you need to use /mnt/e/Study/Codes .

Comment: @Chinmay Thanks, this works: `cd /D/SystemFolders/Downloads/crap`
One has to put the forward-slash infront of the drive letter.

Comment: Running git bash on Windows 10, this solution did not work for me. An answer below suggested using `cd e:` instead, and that worked.

Comment: @ponir's solution is the one that works perfectly.

Answer (score 53):

Just consider your drive as a folder so do `cd e:`

Comment: @Choco Thanks!. I am happy I could help. And yet I got downvoted some days ago :/

Comment: Didn't downvote, but for some reason, `cd e:` works but the autocomplete doesn't. It only autocompletes if I use `cd /e/`.

Answer (score 20):

**TL;DR; for Windows users**:

(*Quotation marks not needed if path has no blank spaces*)

**Git Bash**:   `cd "/C/Program Files (x86)/Android"`      `// macOS/Linux syntax`

**Cmd.exe**:        `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android"`  `// windows syntax`

---

When using `git bash` on windows, you have to:

- remove the colon after the drive letter
- replace your back-slashes with forward-slashes
- If you have blank spaces in your path: Put quotation marks at beginning and end of the path

**Git Bash**:   `cd "/C/Program Files (x86)/Android"`      `// macOS/Linux syntax`

**Cmd.exe**:        `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android"`  `// windows syntax`

Answer (score 16):

**How I do it in Windows 10**

Go to your folder directory you want to open in git bash like so

[image]

After you have reached the folder simply type `git bash` in the top navigation area like so and hit enter.

[image]

A git bash for the destined folder will open for you.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this one but it did not work for me. It opens the window but close it immediately afterwards.

Comment: Same as @JackGrinningCat for me. Did you change something in your setup for that to work Abdullah Khan ?

Comment: No i simply installed the git. The installation gave me git bash and git cmd. And this solution works great for me.

Comment: This worked for me, but I skipped the `git` part and just did `bash`. Also, my `/C:` directory is `/mnt` for some reason. No idea why. Regarding the above questions, I have the linux box for windows 10+ enabled. You might be seeing that crashing on bash command if you haven't enabled bash.

Comment: This is the best answer for my case: Only `bash` works for me! Windows 10 1803 windows-subsystem for linux (WSL) with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Just Try this. $ cd /d/my_folder

Answer (score 9):

In order to navigate to a different drive/directory you can do it in convenient way (instead of typing cd /e/Study/Codes), just type in cd[Space], and drag-and-drop your directory Codes with your mouse to git bash, hit [Enter].

Comment: This worked for my network drive; apparently `G:` is actually `//tsclient/G`

Answer (score 9):

Another approach, which worked for me even though none of the above (didn't try the GUI approach, tbf) did.
As per [super user](http://superuser.com/questions/441491/ddg#441495), try:

```sh
e:
```

That's it. No `cd`. works in gbash and windows cmd.

Answer (score 7):

I tried various forms, and finally, This worked for me:

```
cd /e/
```

Answer (score 6):

Now which drive letter did that removable device get?

Two ways to locate e.g. a USB-disk in `git Bash`:

```
    $ cat /proc/partitions
    major minor  #blocks  name   win-mounts

        8     0 500107608 sda
        8     1   1048576 sda1
        8     2    131072 sda2
        8     3 496305152 sda3   C:\
        8     4   1048576 sda4
        8     5   1572864 sda5
        8    16         0 sdb
        8    32         0 sdc
        8    48         0 sdd
        8    64         0 sde
        8    80   3952639 sdf
        8    81   3950592 sdf1   E:\

    $ mount
    C:/Program Files/Git on / type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
    C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin on /bin type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
    C:/Users/se2982/AppData/Local/Temp on /tmp type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,usertemp)
    C: on /c type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
    E: on /e type vfat (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
    G: on /g type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
    H: on /h type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

... so; likely drive letter in this example => `/e` (or E:\ if you must), when knowing that C, G, and H are other things (in Windows).

Answer (score 5):

Just write `cd E:Study/Codes` and it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why but in my git bash I had to include the colon for the drive letter

```
cd c:/inetpub/wwwroot/blah
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it on Windows 10 is
`cd /D F:\path`

Do not forget to write `\D` in front of the path in order to change drives.

Answer (score 0):

To change from C drive to D drive in git bash

cd /D

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34864163)