# How do I change the directory from bin to what I want to?

Tags: git-bash

Really new to git bash. My current directory is bin. How do I change the directory back to the original folder that I want? Using cd gives an error that no such file or directory exists.

Comment: What is your original folder? Run `pwd` will give you the absolute path of current directory

Comment: Running pwd gives the path as /bin. My original folder was in my documents and the path was something like this: Documents/folder/myfolder...

Comment: `cd` should be followed by a relative or absolute path to the target directory (and some special 'shortcuts' depends on your shell). The absolute path starts with an '/'. I suspect you typed in `cd Documents/folder/myfolder...` then that probably wouldn't work. The 'documents' or the home directory's location depends your operating system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory

Comment: we hope you could find some consistent documentation about Git.

Comment: Right. I was just doing that. I got it working again. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change drive in git bash for windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563826/change-drive-in-git-bash-for-windows)