# Accessing the desktop from GITBASH

Tags: git-bash

I am using git bash for windows and I am trying to access my desktop. When I enter the command 
cd ~/desktop
I get the following message:

bash: cd: /h//desktop: No such file or directory

What am i doing wrong?

See attached screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOG4b.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change drive in git bash for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563826/change-drive-in-git-bash-for-windows)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

right click on the mouse when you are in desktop and choose Git Bash Here, then your present working path will be '~/Desktop/'

or if you just want to use 'cd' to change your working path,then maybe the first letter of 'desktop' should be capitalized. Which means:

```
$cd ~/Desktop
```

Comment: If this answer helped then mark as answered @SamRao

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

'Desktop' is moved to 'OneDrive' in Windows.

```
cd ~/OneDrive/Desktop
```

Comment: This worked for me in Windows 11. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to know the present directory you are using pwd

Then check is desktop is among the directories in that present one use ls

If not, use cd ~ to get your home directory and from there too look is the desktop is there.

Typing desktop or Desktop doesn't stop you from getting to the desktop, the error is telling that desktop isn't among the directoryies in home location

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command:

```
cd ~
```

Then:

```
cd Desktop
```