# Why can't I use "more" command in Git Bash?

Tags: git-bash, less-unix

"less" command works fine, though.

I can use "less" to display part of the file on the screen.

Supposedly, there is a "more" command, but when I type it in, it says "bash: more: command not found."

Comment: Because `more` is not installed in git-bash. You can run `which less` to check where `less` is installed.

Comment: Git bash is not unix. It doesn’t contain the unix programs. Although I’m pretty sure less and more are synonyms for the same program

Comment: @ocras_ren : You could switch from git-bash to Cygwin, or use WSL. Then you have more available, though I don't see why you want to prefer this over `less`.

Answer (score 11):

You can benefit from the Windows more though:

```
alias more=/proc/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/more.com
```

(This does not imply Cygwin: the `git bash` packaged with [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) is based on [MSys2](https://msys2.github.io/), a stripped down version of Cygwin, actively kept up-to-date with Cygwin's source code)

That will work:

```
cat large_file | more
```

The bash alternative:

```
alias more="less -de"
```

([as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770778/why-cant-i-use-more-command-in-git-bash/63771420#comment112776876_63771420): adding `-d` for `--dumb` and `-e` for `--quit-at-eof` makes this alias closed to what more does by default)

In both instances, you can add that alias in your `%USERPROFILE%/.bashrc`.

See also "[In git bash how to increase less's screen width?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322618/6309)" to understand what `less.exe` is in that Windows context.

> The reason is that Git for Windows uses a version of `less` that relies on the MSYS2 runtime to interact with the pseudo terminal (typically inside a MinTTY window, which is also aware of the MSYS2 runtime).

Comment: Please fix your first alias. It assumes that the OP has Cygwin installed, but if he really had, he would have the Gnu `more` already (which as this is included in the Cygwin distribution).

Comment: I think if you want to make `less` behave pretty much like `more`, the alias should be `alias more="less -de"`.

Comment: I don't have cygwin installed myself, just the regular git bash from git for windows. So there is nothing to fix. It does work. Without cygwin.

Comment: So, why are you using _cygdrive_ as part of the path? AFIK, git bash does not use the cygdrive convention to access the Windows drives, does it? I don't have git bash, so I can't verify it.

Comment: Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563826/change-drive-in-git-bash-for-windows#38563857) discussion, the C-drive is supposed to be accessed by `/C`, while you are locating it via `/proc/cygdrive/c`. Are both ways officially supported? I did not find the latter one documented.

Comment: It does work with git bash.

Comment: @user1934428 For more on git bash based on MSYS2, for of Cygwin, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I learned from it, that MSys2 (i.e. the base for GitBash) was _a stripped down version of Cygwin_, which probably explains, why you can see i.e. the _cygdrive_ pathes under /proc , just like in Cygwin.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, I wrote those answers a few years ago, so that is why seeing `/proc/cygdrive/c` did not raise any concern for me.