# In git bash how to increase less's screen width?

Tags: windows-10, less, windows-console

I am using git bash 2.32 on Windows 10.

In git bash after updating to 2.32 I see strange behavior of the command I used for displaying log:

```
git -c core.pager='less -S -F' log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

As you can see I try to use "a dog" command with `less` pager configured to quit on EOF and to cut lines whose length exceed the current screen width.
But after I updated to 2.32 the output appears to be truncated after 80 symbols which is usually much less than the actual screen width (as shown on the image below).

I am trying to understand how to increase that limit so that `less` truncates lines that are longer than say 160 symbols or rather the lines that just don't fit the current screen.

Note: I changed the width to 160 and now `echo $COLUMNS` returns 160 but that didn't help a bit.

Note: I also enabled `checkwinsize` option for the current session. Also no luck.
[image: As can be seen the lines are truncated way too early]

Comment: Have you tried just running `reset` in the terminal?

Comment: I'm surprised the `$COLUMNS` trick didn't work; this implies that `less` is getting the size directly from the terminal emulator, which should be reporting the correct size and hence you shouldn't need to do anything at all. Anyway, I updated tags to direct the question to (I would hope) those who might know. This isn't a Git thing at this point: Git just runs `less` and `less` takes care of everything from there on.

Comment: @Mort `reset` didn't work(

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems to only be an issue when `git` launches `less`. If I run `less` on a file with long lines it uses the full terminal width.

Comment: @Tanj, yeah, same here

Comment: Same issue here ! Scrolling with arrow keys is completely broken, with the page keys it's better but still not using the full width !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a relatively recent Git-for-Windows bug, with discussion and patches found [here](https://lore.kernel.org/git/pull.982.git.1623701952823.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/T/) in the archives for the Git mailing list.  There is a lot of further discussion in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3235).  The bug is to be fixed in the next update of Git-for-Windows.

In the meantime, consider [this workaround from KalleOlaviNiemitalo](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3235#issuecomment-859624668):

```
git config --global core.pager "env -u COLUMNS less"
```

Comment: This fix does not solve the problem in my case. Behavior is very similar (and still indescribable, at least for me).

Comment: @Charles: Try unsetting ROWS as well, perhaps.

Comment: `env -u COLUMNS ROWS less` ?

Comment: `env -u COLUMNS -u ROWS less`. Not having a Windows setup, I can't test this...

Comment: Hm, well, your particular problem may not be the one that's being fixed, then. The description does sound slightly different (what with the output shrinking as you move).

Comment: I must improve my description then. And then let's close the question I opened too soon.

Comment: Okay, actually it seems I was setting the pager wrong, this fix (with `env -u COLUMNS` only even) does work for me as well.

Comment: By "works" I mean now long lines are being correctly wrapped. It doesn't look great but at least this is a correct wrap and it looks so much more readable. As for me I'd rather have "<" symbol instead of word wrap for long lines but this workaround really helps, thanks.

Comment: @daniel.kish: `less` can hide the parts of long lines that don't fit; when it does so, you can use arrow keys or letters to scroll left and right. To make `less` do that, set the `-S` option. (There are numerous ways to set and clear options in `less`, including `$LESS` in the environment, arguments to the `less` command, and at the `:` prompt.) Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to *mark* lines that have been chopped-off like this (no `<` symbol, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

The issue "[Duplicated lines when moving in pager #3235](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3235)" will be fixed with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021).
You can test it today with [Git for Windows snapshots](https://wingit.blob.core.windows.net/files/index.html).

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1185677/119397646-b889e480-bcd6-11eb-882d-0821a97b7eeb.png]

(see duplicate lines at the top)

**Root cause**: when we cannot figure out how wide the terminal is, we use a fallback value of 80 ourselves (which cannot be avoided), but when we run the pager, we export it in `COLUMNS`, which forces the pager to use the hardcoded value, even when the pager is perfectly capable to figure it out itself.

Stop exporting `COLUMNS` when we fall back on the hardcoded default value for our own use.

See [commit 9b6e2c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b6e2c8b98f6a382a6ee8d9110bfe93b1b48d6a7) (21 Jun 2021) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 32d6280](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32d62802266328f0beb8aede853f6e25e8cbc00f), 08 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pager`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b6e2c8b98f6a382a6ee8d9110bfe93b1b48d6a7): avoid setting `COLUMNS` when we're guessing its value
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> We query `TIOCGWINSZ` in Git to determine the correct value for `COLUMNS`, and then set that environment variable.
>
> If `TIOCGWINSZ` is not available, we fall back to the hard-coded value 80 *and still* set the environment variable.
>
> On Windows this is a problem.
> The reason is that Git for Windows uses a version of `less` that relies on the MSYS2 runtime to interact with the pseudo terminal (typically inside a MinTTY window, which is also aware of the MSYS2 runtime).
>
> Both MinTTY and `less.exe` interact with that pseudo terminal via `ioctl()` calls (which the MSYS2 runtime emulates even if there is no such thing on Windows).
>
> Since https://github.com/gwsw/less/commit/bb0ee4e76c2, `less` prefers the `COLUMNS` variable over asking ncurses itself.
>
> But `git.exe` itself is *not* aware of the MSYS2 runtime, or for that matter of that pseudo terminal, and has no way to call `ioctl()` or `TIOCGWINSZ`.
>
> Therefore, `git.exe` will fall back to hard-coding 80 columns, no matter what the actual terminal size is.
>
> But `less.exe` is totally able to interact with the MSYS2 runtime and would not actually require Git's help (which actually makes things worse here).
> So let's not override `COLUMNS` on Windows.
>
> Let's just not set `COLUMNS` unless we managed to query the actual value from the terminal.
>
> This fixes [`git-for-windows/git` issue 3235](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3235)